# Selecting last record by date and version

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure:

[image: here is the screenshot]

I'm trying to get the last record of each code, date type and details based on the version.

I tried group by but that didn't work I used MAX function but that only give me the max value of each version.

I'm using SQLServer database.

Comment: Have a look at this and tell me which one fits your expected result. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb3424696dcc71225e14f1bb16dc1a7c

Comment: Hi, have you had a chance to further look at your problem?

Comment: did you ever solve the problem? It's a bit unproductive for stackoverflow if you disappear and never look at the answers.

Comment: thank you @MenelaosBakopoulos i did solve the problem using your answer, i did upvote but the site not taking into concideration my upvote

Comment: Hi, Happy new year! If it solved your problem, please click on "Accept Answer" . It's not necessary to upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by Code order by date desc) rn
from table
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

using row_number, you can achieve this.

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by Code order by version desc) rn
from table
) x where x.rn=1
```

Comment: @Tanner : look closely. you will find the diff.

Answer (score 0):

## Intro

Since I'm not entirely sure what the OP is going for, I made three different answers. It's not clear for example which colulmns would be used in the group-by statement or if they want the code to be destinct per day or for all data.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb3424696dcc71225e14f1bb16dc1a7c

```
create table data(
code varchar(20),
date integer,
version int,
type varchar(20),
details varchar(20)); 

insert into data values ('x121',01022018, 1, 'r','SOME DETAILS');
insert into data values ('x121',01022018, 3, 'r','SOME DETAILS');
insert into data values ('x121',01022018, 2, 'r','MORE DETAILS');

insert into data values ('x22',01022018, 1, 'b','SOME DETAILS');
insert into data values ('x64',01022018, 2, 't','SOME DETAILS');

insert into data values ('x121',01012018, 1, 'r','SOME DETAILS');
insert into data values ('x121',01012018, 2, 'r','SOME DETAILS');
```

## 1) Join between original data and list of Max Versions

```
select '1) Join between original data and list of Max Versions';

select  d.code, d.date, d.version, d.type, d.details from
(select code, max(version) as maxVersion from data
group by code) maxVersions,
data d
where d.version = maxVersions.maxVersion and d.code = maxVersions.code;
```

## 2) First try using nested query in where condition

```
select '2) First try using nested query in where condition';

SELECT t.code, t.date, t.version, t.type, t.details
FROM data t
WHERE VERSION =
    (SELECT max(VERSION)
     FROM data t2
     WHERE t2.Code = t.Code
       AND t2.Date = t.Date
       AND t2.type = t.type)
;
```

## 3) Grouping by each code, date type and details

```
select '3) Grouping by each code, date type and details ';

select  d.code, d.date, d.version, d.type, d.details from
(select code, type, details, max(version) as maxVersion from data
group by code, type, details) maxVersions,
data d
where d.version = maxVersions.maxVersion and d.code = maxVersions.code
order by d.date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by Code, [type] order by [Date],[Version] desc) rn
from #Codedetails
) x where x.rn=1
```